# Draw canvas on widget android

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I'm trying to draw the canvas on widget, but I have nothing. I have a form with imageviev on which the bitmap, which I will draw all the beauty, but it did not draw ... Here is a piece of my code, what it not work?

My provider where i draw

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

private Bitmap bmp;
private RemoteViews views;

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(16);


    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 16, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);

    c.drawText("fdgfdgfdgfdfdfdgGFDFGFDDDDG", 0, 0, paint);

     views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, bmp);
}
```

}

and my main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="8dip"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Please state if it gives you error or it just not draw, and if it gives you error provide logcat/stacktrace.

Comment: it just not draw, no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put different values for x and y. Currently it is drawing but out side the bounds of bitmap... so try that..

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have several problems, but this may help with a couple.

First your onUpdate method needs to be able to service each of the widgets whose IDs are being passed to you. Note that users can create several instances of your widget on one or more screens at the same time. So the first thing you need to do is create a loop to draw into all of them.

Next, you need to notify the widget manager when each of those widgets is ready to be updated.

You may also need to use a different BitMap depth. ALPHA_8 doesn't work in my test showing only black but ARGB_4444 does.

Note also that you Bitmap and RemoteViews member variables are hiding the ones that you create in the body of your method. I recommend removing the RemoteViews member, and the stack Bitmap.

Putting this all together, here is what the result will look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 16, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for(int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(...);
            ...
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, bmp);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
```

You may face other problems as well. For instance, it is important that all graphics calls be performed on the graphics thread. Implementing a widget is much more complicated than an app. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
```