# Android - Resizable Widgets: Scale TextSize and Keep Aspect Ratio

Tags: java, android, xml, resize, widget

i have a Widget with the size of 130*160dip. I want to make a Resizable Widget of it, i already added `android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"` but since my layouts are fixed size resizing doesnt affect anything.

My Layout (i think thats better than the xml :) ):

```
==========LinearLayout===========
=         -TextView-            =
= =LinearLayout= =LinearLayout= =
= =  TextView  = =  TextView  = =
= =  TextView  = =  TextView  = =
= =  TextView  = =  TextView  = =
= =  TextView  = =  TextView  = =
= =  TextView  = =  TextView  = =
= =  TextView  = =  TextView  = =
= ============================= =
=          TextView             =
=================================
```

If the user resizes the widget, the Aspect ratio (13*16) should keep, and the textviews should be resized according to the new size.

For one of my activities i have used following in a extended Custom (Weight-Based)Layout:

```
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            [...]
        int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            [...]
        if (child instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) child).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                    ch * 7 / 10); //ch=child height 
        }
    }
```

that is working well, but i cant use custom Layouts (or TextViews) for Widgets.

How can i get this behaviour when resizing the Widget?

Metin

Comment: nobody an idea? do i have to create a canvas, save it to bmp and set a  imageview? i think that would be very innefficient for a widget updating minutely

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution myself: use a canvas ([Draw canvas on widget android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009342/draw-canvas-on-widget-android)) and with onAppWidgetOptionsChanged you can get the correct size to use :)

it's bit more tricky than using xml-layouts, but works quite good.

btw: i never have used fixed sizes when drawing the canvas, i always used something like width/10 to make anything scaled.